# ASP.NET C# MVC 2 Web App: PropertiesMustMatch?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2-validation

For some reason, PropertiesMustMatch has absolutely no effect. Do I need to make some other connection beyond what the project built for me?

Also, by adding a new PropertiesMustMatch bind for ConfirmEmail, that also has no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where in the project is that line located? Or is it in the .NET library itself? Can you show some stack trace?

Comment: Is this some code you wrote or is it part of the default project template?

Comment: It's the default project template... I've done nothing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently MVC 2 doesn't recognize PropertiesMustMatch. Here's the real answer... as unpleasant as it is: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/stuartleeks/asp-net-mvc-adding-client-side-validation-to-propertiesmustmatchattribute?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)